# Is there any chance to run ClearCase Remote client under Fedora 14?

Tags: fedora

I'm using Fedora 14 as main dev-env PC and spent time of trying to setup CCRC 7.1 to my desktop. The problem is - while installation when I presses install button - nothing happens. No error message and no actions. As I understood Fedora isn't supported by IBM, is ther any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [System Requirement for CCRC](http://System%20Requirements%20for%20the%20ClearCase%20Remote%20Client), Fedora is indeed not supported.

But a CCRC client is an RCP-based application, or an **Eclipse plugin**.

So if you can make an Eclipse3.6.2 runs in your Fedora setup, chances are you will be able to get the plugin from the CCRC server and make CCRC works that way.

Note: make sure you have the same (or compatible) version between your [CCRC client and CM server](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?mynp=OCSSSH27&mync=E&uid=swg21450012&myns=swgrat).